# Entity Framework Core query where nested collection matches another collection returns wrong results

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, linq-to-sql

I am having a problem with Entity Framework Core 5.x where the "wrong" query is being generated when trying to find the collection of entities where a navigation property collection contains all elements from another list.

Given the following simplified (but standard many-to-many) model

```
public class Announcement {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<AnnouncementTag> Tags { get; set; }
}
    
public class Tag {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; } 
    public virtual IEnumerable<AnnouncementTag> Announcements{ get; set; }
}

// Needed since EF Core does not support many-to-many without explicit JOIN class
public class AnnouncementTag {
    public string AnnouncementId { get; set; }
    public string TagId { get; set; }
    public Announcement Announcement { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to get the list of Announcements which have **all of their tags** match what is in a given list.

For example, with the following data

```
Announcement 1    has Tags A, B
Announcement 2    has Tags B
Announcement 3    has Tags C
```

A query for "all announcements with tags ["B"]" would return Announcement 2 since Announcement 3 has nothing that matches and Announcement 1 only matches on one tag.

I would have thought that the following LINQ query for return the results that I want

```
var applicableTags = new [] { "B" };

var results = db.Announcements.Where(a => a.Tags.All(at => applicableTags.Contains(at.Tag.Id));
```

But that results in all Announcements coming back. Just to simplify the query, I modified it to **use** the JOIN class directly (TagId = Tag.Id)

```
var results = db.Announcements.Where(a => a.Tags.All(at => applicableTags.Contains(at.TagId));
```

But that results in the same where all Announcements are returned. The generated query seems odd

```
SELECT * FROM [Announcements] AS [a]
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [AnnouncementTag] AS [a1]
    INNER JOIN [Tags] AS [t1] ON [a1].[TagId] = [t1].[Id]
    -- Really... <>... opposite of what I would have expected
    -- When I query for more than one Tag...say A,B...the <> becomes "NOT IN"
    WHERE ([a].[Id] = [a1].[AnnouncementId]) AND ([t1].[Id] <> N'B')
)
```

I was able to duplicate this behavior with LINQ-to-Objects so it does **not** seem to be an Entity Framework thing... just me not understanding how to generate the query.

I did find one article that stated the following work

```
// Notice how the applicableTags and Tags criteria is flipped from previous query
var results = db.Announcements.Where(a => applicableTags.All(at => a.Tags.Any(t => t.Id == at)));
```

And it does...but only for LINQ-to-Objects. For Entity Framework, you get the following exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Announcement>()
  .Where(a => __applicableTags_0
      .All(at => DbSet<AnnouncementTag>()
          .Where(a0 => EF.Property<string>(a, "Id") != null && object.Equals(
              objA: EF.Property<string>(a, "Id"),
              objB: EF.Property<string>(a0, "AnnouncementId")))
          .Any(a0 => a0.TagId == at)))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'
```

But I would not want to have to bring back **all** Announcements in order to further filter on the server.

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong? Can somebody please explain the flaw in my original query that is returning the unexpected results?

Comment: The original shown query returns exactly 1 result. `NOT EXISTS ... <> ` is because `All(cond)` is equivalent of `!Any(!cond)`. May be you are trying to do achieve  else.  The problem is that the "flipped" query criteria cannot be translated to SQL.

Comment: Hello Ivan. Not sure I understand your comment.  What I am trying to achieve is a query where announcements are returned where **all** of its associated tags match what is included in the query. So, if I query for tags "a" and "b", only announcements that have **only** "a" and "b" are turned. Announcements with "a" **or** "b" are not returned...nor are announcements that have "a", "b", and "c". Does that clarify the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that tags are unique, you can express your query in the following way:

```cs
var tagCount = applicableTags.Length;

var results = db.Announcements
    .Where(a => a.Tags.Where(t => applicableTags.Contains(t.Id)).Count() >= tagCount);
```

Comment: Well, this answer is acceptable for you or not? I have written a lot of LINQ to know that this answer is close to your needs.

Comment: Changing you query to `.Where(a => a.Tags.Where(at => applicableTags.Contains(at.Tag.Id)).Count() == tagCount && a..Tags.Count == tagCount)` fixed it. I am curious as to why using `All` in my original query did not do what I expected.  As I understand it, the idea was "match announcements where `All` of its Tags appeared in the `applicableTags` list".